# Locate a desktop shortcut with the command prompt or Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to use the command prompt or Powershell to locate some of the shortcuts that an installed program has created on my desktop.  For Example, Adobe Reader has created a shortcut on my desktop.  I try to use dir "c:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop", but I do not see this shortcut.

How can I find this shortcut through a command prompt or with powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortcuts are files with extension ".lnk" and would be displayed by dir ( cmd and powershell)

I think some shortcuts (.lnk files) are created at `c:\users\public\Desktop` so that they can be shared by all users. ( shortcuts placed in this location are available on the desktop of all the users)

More about the "Public user" here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Sharing-files-with-the-Public-folder

So you may want to look in that location as well.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  These links were found in the public user's desktop directory.  Thanks!